# QuickBooks Online SDK - PECL OAuth / Composer

Tags: oauth, composer-php, quickbooks-online, pecl

I'm in the middle of integrating QB Online and the documentation says it requires PECL OAuth at: http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth

I'm not too familiar with using OAuth itself, or how PECL works. I've just been using Composer mostly. So on that note, is there a way for me to install the required OAuth using Composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PECL are extensions, written in C, for PHP. They add functions/methods to the PHP language.

There's no way to install PECL extensions via Composer right now, however, the `pickle` project aims to fix that someday soon:

https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/pickle

Generally, you'd install PECL extensions via your OS package manager. e.g. in Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo pecl install oauth
```

More info:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

If you get stuck, and need a QuickBooks Online PHP lib that doesn't rely on the PECL extension, you might try this one (disclaimer - I'm the author):

http://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the explanation. It's making more sense now I think. So rather than a project dependency, it's more like it needs to be installed for the server itself?

Comment: Correct, it's a PHP extension that needs to be installed on the server itself.

Comment: Composer is for installing pure-PHP code bundles. PECL is for actual PHP extensions written in C.